# Библиотеки в C#

Tags: c#, библиотеки

Понимаю тупой вопрос но есть ли в C# библиотеки.

Comment: В C# есть библиотеки.

Comment: вы можете подключить dll через ссылки либо установить пакеты (так называются библиотеки в шарпе) через пакетный менеджер NuGet, он встроен в VisualStudio

Comment: @tym32167: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD стыдно такое ответом писать :)

Comment: @tym32167: Ну, ответ в точности соответствовал бы вопросу

Comment: @VladD то есть был бы такого же низкого качества

Comment: @tym32167 зато все бы пользователи видели прямой ответ на прямой вопрос.

Comment: @Blackmeser ок ок, уговорили.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дв, в C# есть библиотеки.

См. также

[Библиотеки классов .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/class-libraries)

[Учебник. Создание библиотеки классов .NET с помощью Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio).

[Управление ссылками в проекте](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019)

[Введение в NuGet](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/what-is-nuget)

Comment: @Николай призывается дабы отметить данный ответ лучшим!

Comment: Не всегда, когда публика уговаривает, следует поддаваться на эти уговоры. Вопрос все же довольно расплывчатый. Из чего следует, что автора интересует именно создание своих библиотек, а не использование существующих?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Да, следовало бы дополнить ответ инфой про нугет и всё такое )

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight обновил